# VB.NET best practice for applications running for a long time?

Tags: vb.net, crash, formclosing

I have made an application in vb.net that can sometimes take several hours to finish up, and i have noticed that it will quite often crash while waiting for some processes to finish.

For example:

My app uses `Form.Show()` to open 3 other forms that are needed in the process of the app. These forms can sometimes take several hours to finish, while they are running, my `mainform` is inactive, and just waiting for `form.formclosing()` events to happen, at which point it will then execute clean up codes and exit the app. My problem is, that when the forms that my maincode spawns closes, it sometimes crashes the app with a "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" error in the windows log files. I know where it crashes, i just dont know how to prevent it from crashing at this point.

So on `mainform.load()` i have addhandlers for the forms:

```
AddHandler Form1.FormClosing, AddressOf Form1Closed
AddHandler Form2.FormClosing, AddressOf Form2Closed
```

And Boolean Dims for later:

```
Dim F1Closed As Boolean = False
Dim F2Closed As Boolean = False
```

The app then displays the forms:

```
Public sub StartForms()
    form1.Show()
    form2.Show()
end sub
```

and thats the end of that sub, and the mainform then goes on standby until:

```
Public Sub Form1Closed()
Try
        F1Closed = True

        If F2Closed = True Then
            CloseApp()
        End If
Catch Err as Exception
System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\Error.txt", Err.ToString)
end try
    End Sub
Public Sub Form2Closed()
Try
        F2Closed = True

        If F1Closed = True Then
            CloseApp()
        End If
Catch Err as Exception
System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\Error.txt", Err.ToString)
end try
    End Sub
```

And my close code:

```
Public Sub CloseApp()
    Try

        For i As Integer = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1

            Dim form As Form = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms(i)

            form.Dispose()
        Next i
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        Me.Dispose()

        Environment.Exit(0)
    End Try
End Sub
```

During the Form1.FormClosing or Form2.FormClosing, the app just crashes with the invocation error as above.

I cant get any more detail on it, even with a try..catch in the events.

Any help would be much appreciated..

Edit:
Added the try..catch i have attempted to use

Comment: You are going to have to improve your exception reporting code so you can actually find out what is going wrong.  Do **not** just log the exception's Message property, use the ToString() method so you can see the stack trace *and* the InnerException.  The latter is what you need to know.

Comment: When it crashes it never logs the error. I suppose i should have posted my try..catch method too, ill have that up in a moment.

Comment: Does your application have a Main method, or can you set it up to use one?  You would be able to put a Try...Catch around your entire application so that when this exception does occur, you can log it without your application crashing.  Chances are, this error is currently happening outside of your Try...Catch statements and is causing the crash.

Comment: I am not sure how i would go about implementing this.. I have a sub that basically starts a lot of the processes, but i cant see how a try..catch will handle exceptions occurring in different subs that arent called directly from the main sub.

Comment: I just made a bare-bones replication of your project, using all of the code you listed above, and I received no error when I closed everything.

Comment: Nope, and i dont always receive the error. On Virtual Machines i get the error every time i run my app, on any physical PC, it rarely crashes, but when it does, its when the app has been running for about an hour or longer. My app is on a usb, and when i run the app, i remove the usb shortly after. Whether that has any impact, i dont know.

Comment: Im wondering whether posting my entire app is a way to go.. Unfortunately it contains about 2000 lines of code per. form (3 forms in total) and sensitive information, so it would take ages to sort that out.. Seems like its something im gonna have to do, because i cannot figure out where the error is.

Comment: I cannot figure out where the issue is coming from. I have removed pretty much everything and just had it display a few text boxes every now and then, and it still crashes. Is there something "deeper in" which could cause this issue? If i keep the USB stick in the computer, or copy the program and run the program from the computer, theres no issues at all.. The mainform is being hidden from view, could that make the garbage collector kick in and clean up what it thought was code that wasnt used?